# IAP consumable triggers twice when buying once

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase

"not solved yet..."

I'm having an issue with my iap consumable packages. The thing is that when I buy one, it duplicates the purchase, making another one without requesting it. The alert View appears double also.

A curious thing: this errors only happens when I make an ipa of my app, and not when debugging it! I can't understand why...

Here is the `productPurchase` method implemented in my main menu where I put the IAP buttons:

```
- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;

    NSString* plistPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XXXXX.plist"];

    if(plistPath != nil){
        int playerSilverCoins = [defaults integerForKey:@"userSilverCoins"];
        int playerGoldCoins = [defaults integerForKey:@"userGoldenCoins"];

        NSArray *coinsItems = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        for (NSDictionary *coinItem in coinsItems) {
            if ([[coinItem objectForKey:@"productId"] isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
                playerSilverCoins = playerSilverCoins + [[coinItem objectForKey:@"silverCoins"] integerValue];
                playerGoldCoins = playerGoldCoins + [[coinItem objectForKey:@"goldenCoins"] integerValue];

                [defaults setInteger:playerSilverCoins forKey:@"userSilverCoins"];
                [defaults setInteger:playerGoldCoins forKey:@"userGoldenCoins"];
                [defaults synchronize];

                NSLog(@"product bought: %@" , productIdentifier);

                NSString *message = nil;
                if([[coinItem objectForKey:@"goldenCoins"] integerValue] == 0)
                    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have bought %d silver coins", [[coinItem objectForKey:@"silverCoins"] integerValue]];
                else
                message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have bought %d golden coins and %d silver coins", [[coinItem objectForKey:@"goldenCoins"] integerValue],[[coinItem objectForKey:@"silverCoins"] integerValue]];

                UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"XXXXX" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];

                NSNumber* achievementContributor = [defaults objectForKey:@"AchievementContributor"];
                if ([achievementContributor intValue] != 1 ) {

                    [[GameCenterAchievement sharedGameCenterAchievement] checkAchievements:_kContributor];
                    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"AchievementContributor"];
                    [[GKAchievementHandler defaultHandler] notifyAchievementTitle:@"Contributor"
                                                                       andMessage:@"Buy a coin pack"];
                }


                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if there's a problem there, or on my IAP classes where I implement the transactions, restore, etc. If someone needs more code, just ask for it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are adding twice listener for that NSNotification ? Than function will be called as many times as you have listeners - make sure you clean that up in proper moment.

Comment: Maybe post a code from where you are raising this notification are when you add listeners - that would help. The one you pasted looks ok.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Can you tell me where I'm adding twice the Notification?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski on my Init method i have a        
       `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];`will that be the second call?

Comment: depends if init is happening twice :) maybe put NSLog before that.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Yeah, indeed, is happening twice, but I don't know why :( oh god...

Comment: Ha :D just put a breakpoint there and check from where it's called ;) I will post an answer.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Yeah, but that only happens when I try it making an IPA (Ad Hoc) and installing it from iTunes. When I debug the app from the Xcode in normal run mode, the init only run once. That's is driving me crazy!

Comment: Hm you must have some differences between Release, Debug configurations. Maybe you have some additional #ifdef macros for that build ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding observer only ones.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
```

Adding listener multiply times will cause a multiple calls of your callback method.
If you are reusing your class - remember to removeObserver after you dealloc it - it won't do it on it's own.